# How to check a string does not contain two different substrings with only one condition?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a string called name. I am interested in cases where name does not contain neither `'bias'` nor `'bn'`. I can implement it using two conditions in two ways as follows:

```
if 'bias' not in name and 'bn' not in name:
   pass
```

Or using Demorgan's law as follows:

```
if not ('bias' in name or 'bn' in name):
   pass
```

Note that name has more characters than `'bias'` or `'bn'` so we cannot have `name not in {'bias', bn'}` as the one-condition case.

**Question:** How can we check whether name string does not contain neither `'bias'` nor `'bn'` with one `in` or one condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of substring to search, basically loop through the list, and using `in` check if it's part of input string or not.

```
name = 'some name'
to_search = ['bias', 'bn']
found_a_string = False
for item in to_search:
    if item in name:
        print(item, 'is a part of ', name)
        found_a_string = True

if found_a_string:
    print("Present")
else:
    print("NA")
```

or

using `any`

```
name = 'some name'
to_search = ['bias', 'bn']

if any(x in name for x in to_search):
    print("Present")
else:
    print("No matches found")
```

Comment: Any is what you want.@Sepide

Answer (score 1):

Use `re` with `findall`, that returns list with the matches:

```
import re
if len(re.findall('bias|bn', name)) == 0:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search` along with a list comprehension we can try:

```py
inp = ["a bias", "a bn", "a bn bias", "other"]
output = ["MATCH" if re.search(r'^(?!.*bias)(?!.*bn)\w+$', x) else "NO MATCH" for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['NO MATCH', 'NO MATCH', 'NO MATCH', 'MATCH']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
^               from the start of the input string
    (?!.*bias)  assert that the substring "bias" appears nowhere
    (?!.*bn)    assert that the substring "bn" appears nowhere
    \w+         then match any word
$               end of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```py
name = 'An string'
if False in [i not in name for i in ['bias', 'bn']]:
    print('Yes')
```

You can also create a function to make it easier:

```py
def IsTrueName(name):
    return False in [i not in name for i in ['bias', 'bn']]

name = 'An string'
if IsTrueName(name):
    print('Yes')
```